# Singleton service with many UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, singleton, nsnotificationcenter

Learning swift and just stuck with one issue. I'm trying to use delegates with `singleton` service. 
With delegate i want to update multiple views, but due to `singleton` implementation delegate keeps last UIView. 
So for example i have 3 UIViews with ids 1, 2, 3. When i'll do in `init` body `self.myservice.delegate = self` and will try to use specific delegate method ex. `myServiceDidUpdate` then in this delegate method accessing `self.viewId` always returning `last id`. 
I guess it's due to `singleton` service implementation and wanted to ask you for help.

***Note***: I need singleton implementation to keep specific variable in service

***Question***: Is that possible to keep 3 instances of my service and also keep variable in that service i need? Or what's the best approach to handle this

***Code***

```
class SimpleView: UIView, AudioServiceDelegate {
    private var audioService = AudioService.shared
    var viewId: String?
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.viewId = NSUUID().uuidString
        self.audioService.delegate = self
    }

    func myServiceDidUpdate(identifier: String?) { <-- identifier coming from service i need to keep it across multiple views
        print("SELF", self.viewId) <-- Keeps always last initialized ID
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
class AudioService {
    static let shared = AudioService()
    var delegate: AudioServiceDelegate?
    var identifier: String?

    ...

    @objc func didUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.delegate?.myServiceDidUpdate(self.identifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep an array of uids , but the best practice for multi-observer is

```
// add observer wherever you want to register for new data
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                           selector: #selector(self.calledMeth),
                           name: .didReceiveData,
                           object: nil)
```

//

```
// post when you want to publish data
NotificationCenter.default.postNotification(name: .didReceiveData, object: nil)
```

---

```
extension Notification.Name {
  static let didReceiveData = Notification.Name("didReceiveData")
  static let didCompleteTask = Notification.Name("didCompleteTask")
}
```

> Delegate is used for 1-1 observing while notificationCenter is used for 1-m

Comment: Just to make sure - should i use delegates only for single instance? something like ViewController ? And when i have to deal with many instances i need to use multi-observer as you provided above

Comment: yes delegate is used for 1-1 observing while notificationCenter is used for 1-m